# Clear Edge Browser Cache Programmatically

Tags: python, windows, caching, browser-cache, microsoft-edge

I have been trying to do this for days, and looking on Stack overflow and many other websites with no luck.

Basically, I need to clear the Microsoft Edge Browser's Cache and Temporary Internet Files. I have found the location to this folder on my own PC, but the path changes dynamically on every PC. I can't just have my program clear the same path everytime as the path will vary with each install.

Here is an example of a file in my Cache:

> C:\Users\patdj\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\Cache\25IS03C2\favicon[1].ico 2 KB

This thing that changes on each install isn't just the username, it's also the random string of numbers you see later on in the path file.

I'm doing this in *Python*, I've used many, many Windows APIs such as win32com, win32inet, etc. I have found some success in finding the Temp files for Internet Explorer using these APIs, but I cannot find how to dynamically and programmatically find the path for Edge's Cache and Temporary Internet Files.

This is the kind of thing I've found for IE, and I figure using something similar to this is what I'm looking for in Edge:

```
print (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE, None, 0))
```

**Disclaimer:** This is not a repost as the only things I could find for the past day and a half were posts about using Windows APIs to find the temporary internet files and cache for Internet Explorer. NOT Edge. I need Edge, not IE. Also, I know Python is not optimal for this kind of thing. I understand that and still wish to work in Python for the sake of experience.